# pandas: compare 2 excel files in pandas, return row where value from one column is present in the other

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pandas

I have two excel files, both contain employee information. File1 is is 195K rows, File2 is less than 100. I need to return the entire row in File1 where the id# from the File2 is present. I've done something like this in PHP but can't sort it out in python/pandas.

I'm looking at the isin() method to work out the selection of rows.

```
df0 = pd.ExcelFile('File1.xlsx').parse('Sheet1')
df1 = pd.ExcelFile('Fil2.xlsx').parse('Sheet1')

print df0[df1['staffid'].isin(df0['staffid'])]
```

The result is "IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided"

Is pandas the right tool for this, or should I look at openpyxl or something else?

Comment: You can do this via VBA. Would need to know what data looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column order is wrong, it should be:

```
df0[df0['staffid'].isin(df1['staffid'])]
```

the error is because `df1` length is not the same as `df0`

You want to find the staffid values in `df0` that are present in `df1`, not the other way around

Comment: Oh. Since I want to return rows from File1 (df0), I thought would want to find the values in df1 that are in df0.

as it happens, I get:
"Empty DataFrame
Columns: [firstname, middleInitial, lastname, staffid, etc...]
Index: []"

could there be an issue with data types between the two dataframes?

Comment: Check the output from df0.info() and df1.info() if needed cast the type using astype(int)

Comment: Different data types, that was the issue. Thanks!